# how can i get my json file to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, slideshow

I am reaching out to see if I can get an answer to a json file that i am having trouble with. I am making a slideshow in edge animate and i am using a json file to plug some images into some place holders (symbolized divs) that i have animating out every 8 sec. or so. I tried getting this info from a tutorial that i watched but i was not able to set up the json file as it should be. when i preview the slide in my browser my images dont load into the placeholders, all i see are grey boxes moving according to the animation. my best guess is that my json file isnt correct thats why its not linking the images to the placeholder. this is my code:

```
var imageArray = new Array();
var currentImage = 0;
var s = sym.getSymbol ("slider_Sym_A");
sym.$("Sample Slide").html("");

$.getJSON("LineA.json", function(data) {
   for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      imageArray.push({"image":data[i].image, "title":data[i].title});

    }
    sym.$("Sample Slide").html(imageArray[currentImage].title);
    s.$("ImageHolderOne1") .css({"background-image":"url('"+imageArray[currentImage].image+"')"});
    s.play("Rest");
});

sym.grabNewImage = function(){
    currentImage++;
    if (currentImage>7){
        currentImage = 0;
}
     s.$("ImageHolderTwo1") .css({"background-image":"url('"+imageArray[currentImage].image+"')"});
}

sym.setOldImage = function(){
   s.$("ImageHolderOne1") .css({"background-image":"url('"+imageArray[currentImage].image+"')"});
   setTimeout(function() {
     s.play("Rest");
   }, 500);
}
```

json:

```
[
  {
"image":"PhotoA.gif",
"title":"Re - Stage"
  },
  {
"image":"PhotoA_1.gif",
"title":"ABDC"
  },
  {
"image":"PhotoA_2.gif",
"title":"W - Stage"
  },
  {
"image":"PhotoA_3.gif",
"title":"C - Stage"
  },
 {
"image":"PhotoA_4.gif",
"title":"Riser"
  },
  {
"image":"PhotoA_5.gif",
"title":"Sign"
  },
  {
"image":"PhotoA_6.gif",
"title":"X - Stage"
  },
  {
"image":"PhotoA_7.gif",
"title":"Jason"
  }
]
```

I appreciate anyone that gives me any input. In the meantime I will continue to try and wrap my head around this.

Comment: You are not saying what the problem is - can you explain what the issue is? (see [ask] for hints) - Having said that, your selectors seem wrong - instead of `$("ImageHolderTwo1")` - you might need to use `$("#ImageHolderTwo1")` if it's an `id` or `$(".ImageHolderTwo1")` if it's a `class` - it applies to all selectors

Comment: Sorry about that. My issue is that my images wont load to my placeholders. they are divs but have no ids or class.

Comment: did you try fixing your selectors?

Comment: Yes, I even gave the divs the same name for the class and then tried an id but still didn't link my images.

Comment: see if my answer helps - do you get any errors in console?

Comment: are the images on the same folder as the HTML file? your image URL (path) may be incorrect... can you confirm the path of one image first and post the URL here?